# How to use loops in terms of input (in C language)?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, scanf

I've been trying to get this code to work but the loop does not seem to work? I am very new to C and I sort of get confused with the syntax of this language. However my loop is not functioning like how I want it to be. I want the if and else statement to work but no matter what input (right or wrong) it always outputs "thank you".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int confirm()
{
 char c;
 printf("Confirm (y/n): ");
 scanf("%c", &c);

 while (scanf("%c", &c))
 {
  if (c = 'Y' && 'y' && 'N' && 'n')
   {
    printf("\nthank you");
    break;
   }
   else
   {
     printf("\nInput not recognised, try again. \n");
     printf("\nConfirm (y/n): ");
     scanf("%c", &c);
   }
}
}

int main(int argc, char* agrv[])
{
confirm();
return 0;
}
```

it won't ask to enter another output when the output is incorrect. It just keeps ending from the if statement, thus the loop is not running?
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your loop - it's the `if` statement that's wrong.

This code compiles, but it does not do what you want it to do:

```
if (c = 'Y' && 'y' && 'N' && 'n')
```

- `=` is an assignment; you need `==` to do a comparison
- `&&` means "AND"; you need `||`, which means an "OR"
- You combine logical expressions, not constants with `&&` or `||`

The condition should be

```
if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || c == 'N' || c == 'n')
```

Also note that when you read single characters with `%c`, your program "sees" all characters, including whitespace. This is a problem, because the `'\n'` left over in the buffer will be passed to your program before `Y` or `N`. To fix this, add a space before `%c` to your format string:

```
scanf(" %c", &c)
//     ^
//     |
//    Here
```

Your code also ignores the first character that it reads. I think this is not intentional, so remove the call of `scanf` before the loop. You should also remove the second `scanf` from the loop, leaving the only call to `scanf` in the loop header.

Comment: Also remove the last `scanf` in the loop. And take care of `EOF`(So that there won't be an infinite-loop)

Answer (score 1):

```
int confirm()
{
    char c;
    printf("Confirm (y/n): ");
    //scanf("%c", &c);//  <---------- needless

    while (scanf("%c", &c)) //<----while loop will do `scanf("%c",&c)`, so previous line should be remove.
    {
         if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || c == 'N' || c == 'n')// <-  &&(AND); ||(OR). Also, be careful that don't be lazy, [c == 'Y' || 'y' || 'N' || 'n'] can't to communicate with computer
        {
            printf("\nthank you");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nInput not recognised, try again. \n");
            printf("\nConfirm (y/n): ");
            scanf("%c", &c);
        }
    }
}
```